# $ab(a^2-b^2)+bc(b^2-c^2)+ac(c^2-a^2)\geq 9.\left[\dfrac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{ab+ac+bc}\right]a.b.c$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I created this problem but I want to learn ,if exists, other solution ways.

$ab(a^2-b^2)+bc(b^2-c^2)+ac(c^2-a^2)\geq 9.\left[\dfrac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{ab+ac+bc}\right]a.b.c$

My answer;

$ab(a^2-b^2)+bc(b^2-c^2)+ac(c^2-a^2)=(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)(a+b+c)$ $\quad$ be like that

then,from all sides,we can make elimination  on "$(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)$",

then inequality be,

$(a+b+c)\ge 9.\left[\dfrac{a.b.c}{ab+ac+bc}\right]$

and we exactly know it is $A.M.\ge G.M.$ , $\Box$

But,if I can't to find this "$ab(a^2-b^2)+bc(b^2-c^2)+ac(c^2-a^2)=(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)(a+b+c)$" still I have any chance for prove this inequality?

Comment: All you need is to make sure that $(a-c)(a-b)(b-c) >0$ in order to preserve the $\geq$ when eliminating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above inequality does not hold. Counter-example: $(a,b,c) = (1,2,0)$.

The mistake that you made in the above solution is eliminating $(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)$ without knowing its sign. Note that $xz \ge yz \Longleftrightarrow x \ge y$ only holds if $z > 0$.

The inequality holds for $a\ge b \ge c \ge 0$ though. And factorizing the LHS as $(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)(a+b+c)$ is the simplest solution.